# Get random cells in a filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

To get a random cell in a filtered range I use this method below but it sometimes selects hidden ones.

How can I restrict random selection to select visible cells?

```
Set areaRng = Sheet1.Range("table_area").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Dim randomCell As Long
randomCell = Int(Rnd * areaRng.Cells.Count) + 1
On Error Resume Next      
With areaRng.Cells(randomCell)
    .Select        
End With`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomize a position within the entire range and cross check that for being within the visible cells.

```
    Dim areaAllRng As Range, areaVisibleRng As Range
    Dim randomCell As Long

    With Sheet6
        Set areaAllRng = .Range("table_area").Cells
        Set areaVisibleRng = .Range("table_area").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        randomCell = Int(Rnd * areaAllRng.Cells.Count) + 1

        Do While Intersect(areaAllRng.Cells(randomCell), areaVisibleRng) Is Nothing
            'Debug.Print areaAllRng.Cells(randomCell).Address(0, 0)
            randomCell = Int(Rnd * areaAllRng.Cells.Count) + 1
        Loop

        Debug.Print areaAllRng.Cells(randomCell).Address(0, 0)
        areaAllRng.Cells(randomCell).Select

    End With
```

Comment: Thank you Jeeped ,again:).So kind of you

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method that doesn't bias the result but still utilises the `Areas` property thus avoiding the risk of run time blowing out on random chance

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rngVisible As Range
    Dim arr As Range
    Dim CellsToCount As Long
    Dim RandCell As Range

    Set rngVisible = Sheet1.Range("table_area").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    CellsToCount = Int(Rnd * rngVisible.Count) + 1

    For Each arr In rngVisible.Areas
        If arr.Cells.Count >= CellsToCount Then
            Set RandCell = arr.Cells(CellsToCount)
            Exit For
        Else
            CellsToCount = CellsToCount - arr.Cells.Count
        End If
    Next

    RandCell.Select

End Sub
```